# Unresolved class '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior' in fragment results into behaviour OnCreate not fired

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Please refer to my below fragment .XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/consulting_frame"
    tools:context=".fragments.ConsultingFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/consulting_tabs"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            **app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>**

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

in the above file line

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

displays error "Unresolved reference" in the editor, however it doesn't generate any compilation error.

I have searched net and stackoverflow to find solution, it has mentioned that

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

must be included in the app gradle file. I have checked it, and both files are there in my app gradle file.

I am not able to resolve the error. Please help with this error.
Further to above error, I am also facing other erratic behaviour in my app, which is as explained below:

When my above `viewpager` (Containing error) is initialized, I am instantiating four tabs and where four fragments are opened. My fragment file is as below:

```
package com.mobiapp.hospmgmt.fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.mobiapp.hospmgmt.R;
import com.mobiapp.hospmgmt.SessionHandler;
import com.mobiapp.hospmgmt.User;
import com.mobiapp.hospmgmt.helper.HospMgmtConstants;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ConsultingFragment extends Fragment {

    private SessionHandler session;
    User user;

    public ConsultingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle(HospMgmtConstants.TAG_CONSULTING);

        session = new SessionHandler(getContext());
        user = session.getUserDetails();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consulting, container, false);
        // Setting ViewPager for each Tabs
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.consulting_tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        return view;

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new PatientConsultingFragment(), "Patient");
        adapter.addFragment(new DiagnosisConsultingFragment(), "Diagnosis");
        adapter.addFragment(new LabtestsConsultingFragment(), "Lab Tests");
        adapter.addFragment(new PrescribeConsultingFragment(), "Prescribe");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, issue is along with first fragment, second fragment is also getting instantiated, and onCreate method is fired for both. However, after that even if, I click on tab-2 (Diagnosis), onCreate is not fired. However, for other two fragments (TAB-3 (Lab Tests) and TAB-4 (Prescribe)) every time onCreate is getting fired whenever those tabs are clicked.

I am failed to understand this erratic behaviour. Is this due to above Unresolved reference? I have tried to remove the line `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`, but above erratic behaviour remains as it is.

So, please help me in resolving above mentioned unresolved reference error and also above erratic behaviour of fragment initialization.

I have even added `<string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" translatable="false">android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>` in the strings.xml, but it has not resolved unresolved class error.

Answer (score 10):

For the `app:layout_behavior`, try:

`app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"`

(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131403371)

Comment: This solution resolves the issue if you use androidX.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue as follows. Since the viewPager caches the fragments into memory for faster performance, it creates two fragment as soon as you create tabbed layout with viewpager. To change the default behaviour, I have added following method into the `FragmentPagerAdapter` class

```
@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

and also called `viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` where data is getting changed in the fragment's `onCreateView()` method.

Unresolved class @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior issue is still not solved, but it appears that it is not affecting the app in any way. This may be a bug in AndroidStudio.

Comment: this seems to be an A.S bug, as it doesn't crash my app.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I even uninstalled AS, restarted my computer, and then installed a fresh copy, created a new project, added all implementation for the design/material lib, but the same error appears in the editor. Project builds without any problems though.